# Using Redis with magento 1.9

Tags: magento, redis

I have a magento setup where I am using one box for apache server and one as mysql server. 
I want to install redis in this installation. I am not sure how I can achieve that.

My questions are:

1. On which box should I install Redis?
2. Is there any step by step tutorial for such setup? As i am new to this.
3. How can I configure magento to use redis server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask over on serverfault.com as stack overflow is a programming oriented stack site and server fault is for configuring servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only using 1 frontend server, I would set it up on that as it will be faster and take additional load off the database network connection.

1.9 has the Cm_RedisSession module included in the codebase and it's a doddle to setup, take a look here for step by step instructions;

http://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks @PixieMedia, that helped. I am getting the error "Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures" when trying to use Redis for backend. I am successfully able to connect to redis using redis-cli. Any thoughts ?